# Como poder agregar a un ArrayList una Clase con constructor por Scanner

Tags: java, lista, poo, scanner

Saludos tengo dos clases que son Empleado y Jefe ambas son de tipo empleado quiero pedir a través de un método los datos por Scanner y agregarlo al ArrayList. Pondre un Ejemplo por si me pueden guiar gracias.No estoy seguro si lo que pretendo hacer se puede y no se me ocurre la forma de como pedir los datos uno a uno y poder ponerlos.

```
empleados=new   ArrayList();
```

//El constructor pide el nombre, sexo, fecha de contratación, y el sueldo

empleados.add(new Empleado("Nombre", 'M', new Fecha(18, 06, 2022), 1000));

//A Su vez un Jefe tiene un parametro más que es el departamento

empleados.add(new Jefe("Nombre", 'H', new Fecha(18, 06, 2022), 1200, "rrhh"));

```
//En el metodo quiero poder agregarlo con Scanner
 public static void altaEmpleado(){
    System.out.println("Introduce el tipo de empleado");
   String tipo= SCAN.nextLine().toLowerCase();
   if(tipo.equals("empleado")){
       empleados.add(new Empleado.);
   }
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agregando un poco de orden puedes hacerlo así:

```
if(tipo.equals("empleado")){
     System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del empleado:");
     String nombre = SCAN.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Ingrese dato x del empleado:");
     String datoX = SCAN.nextLine();
     empleados.add(new Empleado(nombre, datoX/*... más propiedades*/));
  }
```

Guardas cada dato en su variable y al final creas el nuevo objeto.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta me ha servido para darme cuenta ahora me encontré un problemita que la fecha es un tipo de dato y al pasarle 3 enteros seguidos no me lo reconoce.

Comment: Puedes hacer lo mismo: ingresar la fecha en una sola línea como `18/06/2022`, la lees como una cadena, luego usas `split` para separar sus partes y con esas partes creas el objeto `Fecha`.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me sirvió mucho la ayuda gracias por los consejos saludos